# Condicion If en TRIGGER UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

Quiero que mi trigger actúe siempre y cuando se cumpla esta condición "IF(#CursorUpdate.Key5 ='P001') " pero tengo errores al ejecutar , soy nuevo en el tema de los Triggers.

```
USE [EpicorTest905]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create trigger [dbo].[tgEpicor_RES1_UD33_Impresion0]
  on [dbo].[UD33]
  for update 
as

if 
   Update(ShortChar01) or 
   Update(ShortChar02) or 
   Update(ShortChar03) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar04) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar11) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar12) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar09) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar10) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar14) or 
   UPDATE(Number01)    or
   UPDATE(Number02)    or
   update(Number03)    or
   update(Number04)    or
   update(CheckBox01)  or
   update(ShortChar05) or
   update(ShortChar06) or
   update(ShortChar07) or
   update(ShortChar08) or
   update(Character05) or
   update(Number05)    or
   update(Number06)    or
   update(Number07)    or
   update(Number08)    or
   update(Number09)    or
   update(Number10)    or
   update(Number11)    or
   update(Number12)    or
   update(Number13)    or
   update(Number14)    or
   update(Number15)    or
   update(Number16)    or
   update(Number17)    or
   update(Number18)    or
   UPDATE(ShortChar16) or 
   UPDATE(ShortChar17) or 
   update(CheckBox03)  or
   UPDATE(ShortChar15) or 
   update(Character01) or
   update(Character03) or
   update(Character02) or
   update(Character04) or
   update(Character06) 



begin 

             Select 
                    i.PROGRESS_RECID as correlativo,
                 
           
                    d.ShortChar01 as CarasLadosCodigo,
                    d.ShortChar02 as CarasLadosDescripcion,
                    d.ShortChar03 as TipoImpresionCodigo,
                    d.ShortChar04 as TipoImpresionDescripcion,
                    d.ShortChar11 as MaterialCodigo,
                    d.ShortChar12 as MaterialDescripcion,
                    d.ShortChar09 as UbicacionCodigo,
                    d.ShortChar10 as UbicacionDescripcion,
                    d.ShortChar14 as TipoBanda,
                    d.Number01    as NumeroColores,
                    d.Number02    as Cilindros,
                    d.Number03    as CantidadBandas,
                    d.Number04    as Repeticiones,
                    d.CheckBox01  as PonerLogoResinplast,
                    d.ShortChar05 as TextoLegal,
                    d.ShortChar06 as UnidadFrecuencia,
                    d.ShortChar07 as UnidadAnchoMaterial,
                    d.ShortChar08 as UnidadEspesorMaterial,
                    d.Character05 as Observaciones,
                    d.Number05    as Frecuencia,
                    d.Number06    as AnchoMaterial,
                    d.Number07    as EspesorMaterial,
                    d.Number08    as GramajeMaterialm2,
                    d.Number09    as GramajeTinta,
                    d.Number10    as GramajeTotal,
                    d.Number11    as AnchoFotoCelula_mm,
                    d.Number12    as LargoFotoCelula_mm,
                    d.Number13    as DistanciaCorteFotocelula_mm,
                    d.Number14    as Sentido,
                    d.Number15    as FactorKgMillar,
                    d.Number16    as AnchoBanda_mm,
                    d.Number17    as Refile_mm,
                    d.Number18    as AnchoRequerido,
                    d.ShortChar16 as ColorCodigo,
                    d.ShortChar17 as ColorDescripcion,
                    d.CheckBox03  as IndRebobinadoEnLinea,
                    d.ShortChar15 as TipoTintaResistenciaCodigo,
                    d.Character01 as TipoTintaResistenciaDescripcion,
                    d.Character03 as ColoresCodigo,
                    d.Character02 as ColoresDescripcion,
                    d.Character04 as ColoresViscocidad,
                    d.Character06 as CodigoDeBarra,

      
       
                    
                    i.ShortChar01,
                    i.ShortChar02,
                    i.ShortChar03,
                    i.ShortChar04,
                    i.ShortChar11,
                    i.ShortChar12,
                    i.ShortChar09,
                    i.ShortChar10,
                    i.ShortChar14,
                    i.Number01,
                    i.Number02,
                    i.Number03,
                    i.Number04,
                    i.CheckBox01,
                    i.ShortChar05,
                    i.ShortChar06,
                    i.ShortChar07,
                    i.ShortChar08,
                    i.Character05,
                    i.Number05,
                    i.Number06,
                    i.Number07,
                    i.Number08,
                    i.Number09,
                    i.Number10,
                    i.Number11,
                    i.Number12,
                    i.Number13,
                    i.Number14,
                    i.Number15,
                    i.Number16,
                    i.Number17,
                    i.Number18,
                    i.ShortChar16,
                    i.ShortChar17,
                    i.CheckBox03,
                    i.ShortChar15,
                    i.Character01,
                    i.Character03,
                    i.Character02,
                    i.Character04,
                    i.Character06,
                    
                    i.Key1 ,
                    i.Key2 ,
                    i.Key3 ,
                    i.Key4 ,
                    i.Key5 ,
            
                

             into #CursorUpdate                       
             from deleted as d
                    join inserted as i on d.PROGRESS_RECID=i.PROGRESS_RECID 

        IF(#CursorUpdate.Key5 ='P001') 

 BEGIN

    

 declare @UsuarioModificacion varchar(50)

          set @UsuarioModificacion = (select Character05 from UD32 (nolock)
                        WHERE Company='C01' and Key1='0120400092' and Key2='1')


             if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where CarasLadosCodigo <> ShortChar01)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar01','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar01',correlativo,
                                        CarasLadosCodigo ,ShortChar01,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
             
              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where CarasLadosDescripcion <> ShortChar02)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar02','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar02',correlativo,
                                        CarasLadosDescripcion ,ShortChar02,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
             
              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TipoImpresionCodigo <> ShortChar03)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar03','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar03',correlativo,
                                        TipoImpresionCodigo ,ShortChar03,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TipoImpresionDescripcion <> ShortChar04)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar04','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar04',correlativo,
                                        TipoImpresionDescripcion ,ShortChar04,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
            
              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where MaterialCodigo <> ShortChar11)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar11','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar11',correlativo,
                                        MaterialCodigo ,ShortChar11,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
                          End

              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where MaterialDescripcion <> ShortChar12)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar12','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar12',correlativo,
                                        MaterialDescripcion ,ShortChar12,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UbicacionCodigo <> ShortChar09)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar09','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar09',correlativo,
                                        UbicacionCodigo ,ShortChar09,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
            
              if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UbicacionDescripcion <> ShortChar10)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar10','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar10',correlativo,
                                        UbicacionDescripcion ,ShortChar10,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
            
            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TipoBanda <> ShortChar14)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar14','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar14',correlativo,
                                        TipoBanda ,ShortChar14,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

             if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where NumeroColores <> Number01)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number01','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number01',correlativo,
                                        NumeroColores ,Number01,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Cilindros <> Number02)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number02','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number02',correlativo,
                                        Cilindros ,Number02,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where CantidadBandas <> Number03)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number03','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number03',correlativo,
                                        CantidadBandas ,Number03,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Repeticiones <> Number04)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number04','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number04',correlativo,
                                        Repeticiones ,Number04,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where PonerLogoResinplast <> CheckBox01)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','CheckBox01','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-CheckBox01',correlativo,
                                        PonerLogoResinplast ,CheckBox01,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TextoLegal <> ShortChar05)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar05','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar05',correlativo,
                                        TextoLegal ,ShortChar05,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
            
            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UnidadFrecuencia <> ShortChar06)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar06','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar06',correlativo,
                                        UnidadFrecuencia ,ShortChar06,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

           if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UnidadAnchoMaterial <> ShortChar07)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar07','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar07',correlativo,
                                        UnidadAnchoMaterial ,ShortChar07,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

           if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UnidadEspesorMaterial <> ShortChar08)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar08','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar08',correlativo,
                                        UnidadEspesorMaterial ,ShortChar08,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 


           if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where UnidadEspesorMaterial <> ShortChar08)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar08','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character05',correlativo,
                                        UnidadEspesorMaterial ,Character05,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

         if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Observaciones <> Character05)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character05','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character05',correlativo,
                                        Observaciones ,Character05,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

         if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Frecuencia <> Number05)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number05','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number05',correlativo,
                                        Frecuencia ,Number05,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where AnchoMaterial <> Number06)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number06','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number06',correlativo,
                                        AnchoMaterial ,Number06,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

          if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where EspesorMaterial <> Number07)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number07','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number07',correlativo,
                                        EspesorMaterial ,Number07,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
        
        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where GramajeMaterialm2 <> Number08)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number08','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number08',correlativo,
                                        GramajeMaterialm2 ,Number08,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where GramajeTinta <> Number09)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number09','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number09',correlativo,
                                        GramajeTinta ,Number09,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
      
      if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where GramajeTotal <> Number10)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number10','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number10',correlativo,
                                        GramajeTotal ,Number10,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
        
        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where AnchoFotoCelula_mm <> Number11)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number11','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number11',correlativo,
                                        AnchoFotoCelula_mm ,Number11,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

     if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where LargoFotoCelula_mm <> Number12)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number12','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number12',correlativo,
                                        LargoFotoCelula_mm ,Number12,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

     if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where DistanciaCorteFotocelula_mm <> Number13)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number13','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number13',correlativo,
                                        DistanciaCorteFotocelula_mm ,Number13,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Sentido <> Number14)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number14','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number14',correlativo,
                                        Sentido ,Number14,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where FactorKgMillar <> Number15)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number15','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number15',correlativo,
                                        FactorKgMillar ,Number15,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 
                           
      if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where AnchoBanda_mm <> Number16)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number16','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number16',correlativo,
                                        AnchoBanda_mm ,Number16,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Refile_mm <> Number17)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number17','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number17',correlativo,
                                        Refile_mm ,Number17,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate 

        
        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where AnchoRequerido <> Number18)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Number18','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Number18',correlativo,
                                        AnchoRequerido ,Number18,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate
         
         if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where ColorCodigo <> ShortChar16)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar16','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar16',correlativo,
                                        ColorCodigo ,ShortChar16,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where ColorDescripcion <> ShortChar17)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar17','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar17',correlativo,
                                        ColorDescripcion ,ShortChar17,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where IndRebobinadoEnLinea <> CheckBox03)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','CheckBox03','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-CheckBox03',correlativo,
                                        IndRebobinadoEnLinea ,CheckBox03,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

         if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TipoTintaResistenciaCodigo <> ShortChar15)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar15','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar15',correlativo,
                                        TipoTintaResistenciaCodigo ,ShortChar15,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

          if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where TipoTintaResistenciaDescripcion <> Character01)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character01','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character01',correlativo,
                                        TipoTintaResistenciaDescripcion ,Character01,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

          if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where ColoresCodigo <> Character03)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character03','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character03',correlativo,
                                        ColoresCodigo ,Character03,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

          if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where ColoresDescripcion <> Character02)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character02','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character02',correlativo,
                                        ColoresDescripcion ,Character02,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

            if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where ColoresViscocidad <> Character04)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character04','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character04',correlativo,
                                        ColoresViscocidad ,Character04,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate

        if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where CodigoDeBarra <> Character06)                    
                    insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                           select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                                  'UD33_Impresion0','Character06','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-Character06',correlativo,
                                        CodigoDeBarra ,Character06,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                           from #CursorUpdate


                          End
end
```

Comment: porque no usas el proceso de Auditoria nativo de Epicor?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x Es un trabajo Propio.

Comment: Montones de lineas de codigo que no dicen nada, porque nunca dijiste cual es el error...

Comment: @gbianchi quiero que mi trigger se ejecute siempre y cuando se de la condicion esta *" IF (#CursorUpdate.Key5 ='P001') " pero tengo un error en ello , como dije soy nuevo en temas con triggers

Comment: un error.. y que error tenes??? sale un error? tira un error? que tipo de error? esa condicion, donde esta en toda esta pared de codigo?

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo el IF está mal planteado, ya que lo estás poniendo como si fuera C#, tienes:

```
IF(#CursorUpdate.Key5 ='P001')
```

cuando debería ser algo así, validando que tu condición se cumpla:

```
IF((select count(*) from #CursorUpdate where Key5 = 'P001') > 0)
```

o en su defecto, podrías poner algo así, en donde espeficicas el valor del Key5:

```
         if exists(select * from #CursorUpdate where Key5 = 'P001' AND CarasLadosCodigo <> ShortChar01)                    
                insert into RES1_LogAuditoria
                       select Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,
                              'UD33_Impresion0','ShortChar01','FichaTecnica','UD33_Impresion0-ShortChar01',correlativo,
                                    CarasLadosCodigo ,ShortChar01,@UsuarioModificacion,GETDATE(),'Editado'
                       from #CursorUpdate
                      where Key5 = 'P001'
```